# SSL error only when using Chrome and DirectAdmin domain pointer

Tags: ssl, domain, redirect, google-chrome

I have a site that has a main domain with a valid SSL certificate and a secondary domain, which only needs to redirect visitors to the main domain. So, for the primary domain everything is set up: valid SSL certificate and a website that shows correctly. For the secondary domain I added a domainpointer that redirects to the main domain. In all browsers this works fine, except for Chrome. Chrome tries to verify the SSL domain of the main domain for the secondary domain. In e.g. Safari the redirect works like a charm. At first I thought it would be a caching issue, but since the configuration of the domain pointer several weeks have passed by. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Main domain: diclaadsystemen.nl
Secondary domain: laadoplossingen.nl

Answer (score 0):

Maybe write for what domain you have a problem? To be honest i had lot of issues with working domain configuration on Chrome (i think that more than in other browsers) and there is a lot of possibilities. In most of cases enough was refresh configuration on server and reconsideration about cache.

Comment: Hi KryDee, thanks for replying. I've added the domains in the question.